# css positioning: item keeps moving whenever the browser is resized

Tags: html, css

The logo image on my website banner refuses to stay put whenever the browser resizes. It will be directly in the middle of the banner where it's suppose to be but as soon as I start to shrink the browser's width, it starts to rise up. Why is this? Can someone please help me fix this?

Below are the html and css codes I am using.

**HTML:**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>BLB</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="TEXT/CSS" HREF="STYLE1.CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 1000px)"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $(".TYPEHERE").fadeToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="page-wrap">

        <h1>
                <div id="logo"><img src="images/blb2.png"></div>

                <div class="cart"><img src="images/cart3.png"></div>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><div id="fb"><img src="images/fb.png"></div>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><div id="insta"><img src="images/insta.png"></div>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><div id="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png"></div>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><div id="tube"><img src="images/tubee.png"></div>


        <ul id="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog.html">Articles</a></li>
          <li><a href="store.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </h1>

    <div id="footer">
<tfooter>&copy;2014 Blacklipbastard.com All Rights Reserved.</tfooter>
</div>

</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**CSS:**

```
html { overflow-y: scroll;}

body { font: 62% helvetica, sans-serif; width: 100%; background: url(images/bg1.jpg); background-size: 200%; }

h1 {background-color: #000; background-size: 100%; position: absolute; height: 18%; width: 100%; left: 0%; top: -1.8%; border-style: solid; border-color: gray; border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0; padding-top: 0%; background-repeat: no repeat; border-width: 2px;}

#logo { position: absolute; top: -140%; left: 22%; width: 50%;}

img {max-width: 100%;}

.cart {position: relative; top: 50%; left: 94%;}

.cart img {width:5%; height:30%;}

#nav {background:url(images/nav2.jpg) ; position: absolute; border-style: solid; left:0%; top:73%; width: 96%; height:19%; border-right: 2px solid #000000;}

#nav li {position: relative; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 10%; top: 20%;  border-right: 2px groove #000; padding: 0 10px;}

#nav a{text-decoration: none; color: white; font-size: 20px; position: relative;}

#nav a:hover{background: url(images/nav.jpg); color: silver;}

#fb {position: absolute; top: 40%; width: 3.5%; top: 89.5%; left: 80%; height: 15%; z-index: 1}
#insta { position: absolute; left: 85%; width: 2.8%; top: 89.5%; height: 13%; z-index: 1}
#twitter { position: absolute; width: 3.5%; top: 89.5%; left: 95%; height: 15%; z-index: 1}
#tube { position: absolute; top: 89.5%; width: 3.5%; left: 90%; height: 15%; z-index: 1}


#fb img{ Width:95%; Height:110%;}
#insta img{ Width:95%; Height:110%;}
#twitter img{ Width:95%; Height:110%;}
#tube img{ Width:95%; Height:110%;}

#footer { position: absolute; font: verdana #fff; left: 2.8%; bottom: 3%; border-top-style: double; border-color:  #E8E8E8  ; padding: 0 48%;  }

tfooter {position: absolute; left: 3%}

#page-wrap{
width: 80%;
height: 150%;
margin: 8.5%;
background: #fff;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
top: -7%;
border-radius: 20px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF, endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF, endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF)";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your image have 100% width. it will automatically scale up when you resize your browser. try adding max-width to the logo. :)

Comment: that fixed it! now the logo doesn't resize. It stays the same size when I resize the browser when everything else shrinks. would you know how to fix that?

Comment: try this CSS, not sure why it doesn't shrink when you resize the browser. 

`width: 100%; max-width: (max image size)px; min-width: (min image size)px;`